# Changing voiced and unvoiced consonants Perl

Tags: perl

I am having trouble getting this code to work:

```
print "Type something:\n";
chomp($word=<STDIN>);
$word=~s/t/d/gi;
$word=~s/p/b/gi;
$word=~s/k/g/gi;
$word=~s/s/z/gi;

$word=~s/d/t/gi;
$word=~s/b/p/gi;
$word=~s/g/r/gi;
$word=~s/z/s/gi;
print "Your voiced/devoiced string is: $word\n";
```

I am attempting to have voiced consonants (T, P, K, S) converted to devoiced consonants (D, B, R, S), and vice versa. After using my code, all voiced consonants are turned to devoiced but immediately converted back to voiced consonants. I'm not quite sure how to have the first set run, and then the second set.

Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`tr`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-Like-Operators) instead:

> `tr/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr`
>
> `y/SEARCHLIST/REPLACEMENTLIST/cdsr`
>
> Transliterates all occurrences of the characters found in the search list with the corresponding character in the replacement list. It returns the number of characters replaced or deleted. If no string is specified via the `=~` or `!~` operator, the `$_` string is transliterated.

Script would be the following:

```
print "Type something:\n";
chomp($word=<STDIN>);

$word =~ tr/tpksdbgzTPKSDBGZ/dbgztprsDBGZTPRS/;

print "Your voiced/devoiced string is: $word\n";
```

Comment: Thank you. This solved my problem, and allows for capital and lowercase usage.